# Dask - how to efficiently execute the right number of tasks

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

I am trying to mask and then apply a `unique` operation on one column. A simplified version of the code i am using is reported below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

data = np.random.randint(0,100,(1000,2))
ddf = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['data','id']), npartitions = 2)

mask = ddf['data'] > 0
unique_false = ddf[~mask]['id'].unique()
unique_true = ddf[mask]['id'].unique()

results = dask.compute([unique_true, unique_false])
```

This quick example works fine. My real data are composed of `~5000` columns, where one column is used to filter and one is to get unique ids. The data are stored in `200` parquet partitions, each of these partitions weights 9MB, but when loaded in memory (`ddf.get_partition(0).compute().info()`) weights `~5GB`. Given that i have around `400GB` of RAM, I would assume that I can load around `80` partitions (maybe less given the overhead of other operations). From the dashboard I can see that dask is trying to execute all task at once (in memory tasks are always the same, it does not matter how many workers).

I wrote this to test the time it takes to process a partition:

```
start = time.time()

df = ddf.get_partition(0).compute()

mask = df['data'] > 0

unique_true = df[mask]['id'].unique()
unique_false = df[~mask]['id'].unique()

print(time.time() - start)
```

It takes around `60s` and it requires around `7GB` of RAM. If I start a ProcessPool and assuming I am only running `50` partitions at a time, it would take `4-5` minutes.

I know the core of Dask exactly does what I did with a single partition, so my question would be why Dask tries to execute all tasks in parallel instead of one at a time? Is there a way to limit the task execution? And is this the real problem here or am I missing something?

I found several questions here to limit task execution. All points here: https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/resources.html. However, I believe I should not force this behavior and let Dask do its best. I should also mention that Dask is able to run the code when setting 5 workers in single thread with 80GB of RAM each (but it takes a lot more than the time it would take with the process pool method i mentioned).

I am on python `3.6.10` and Dask `2.17.2`.